# Color Specific inventory list

Tags: colour

I can't seem to figure out the correct colors for Model #7150 TIE Fighter & Y-Wing inventory list.  My son has four different colors of "gray".  Two seem to be warmer in tone (almost a khaki color), and two seem to be coolor in tone (truly more gray).  He also has a blue-ish slate gray (more light blue than gray).  When the inventory specifies "old gray," is it referring to the light (khaki) gray?  And is the "old dark gray" the darker (khaki) gray?  Or is the inventory referring to the more cooler (truly gray) grays?  I'm SO CONFUSED!  Please help me!

Comment: Hi Kathleen and welcome to LEGO Answers - thanks for joining :) I hope that the linked question "What is the bely/blay color" helps you distinguish between these colours. You may also find Peeron.com useful as well: http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/7150-1. As this set is fairly old, it uses the older, "warmer" greys rather than the newer bleys.

Comment: This shouldn't have been closed. Two different questions, although the linked one is related.

Answer (score 3):

Also keep in mind that color will change on some parts as they age (depending on environmental factors). New or less exposed parts in the "old grey" can be a different shade than original, aged parts in the same "old grey".  The blue-grey parts that you have might actually be categorized as a blue instead.

Check out how lego sells the colors today, here:
http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Pick-A-Brick-11998

The peeron color table is here:
http://www.peeron.com/inv/colortable/3020

Check out your set here as well:
http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7150-1

The colors in the grey family (or sometimes confused as grey) are referred to as on brick set (on peeron if different):
Black
Dark Grey (OldDkGray)
Dark Stone Grey (DkStone)
Grey (OldGray)
Medium Stone Grey (Stone)
Sand Blue

Your set has "Grey" and "Black" from this list.  If you ordered new parts from Lego, the lighter shade of grey would be "Medium Stone Grey" form this list.